# MySQL - jdbc connection connects to incorrect schema. Fetched data from wrong schema

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Project Technologies: Java spring hibernate + MySQL

I have created a replica schema say "abc_uat" from my production schema "abc" on the same server.

I changes connection string in Java code to point to new replica schema (abc_uat), as follows -

```xml
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://abc.com:3306/ABC_UAT?autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="username" value="user" />
            <property name="password" value="pass" />
```

Earlier the connection details used to be like this -

```xml
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://abc.com:3306/ABC?autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="username" value="user" />
            <property name="password" value="pass" />
```

Surprisingly, when I run this program, MySQL still connects with "abc" schema and not "abc_uat".

During debug, I can see Java code is properly creates connection to new schema (abc_uat), however, the data that is received back is from production schema( abc).

Here is how I had created replica -

I used export data into sql dump file on "abc" and then import data function to create tables and data into "abc_uat".

Can someone please point me, what am I missing?

Comment: try creating a unique table change in your UAT table and check if it is showing up via your code? because you had created your dump from prod, so might not be able to figure out

Comment: Sounds like something in your application code or configuration explicitly sets the catalog to `abc`,

Comment: Hi! I have the exact same problem currently. Upgraded to latest spring-jdbc/5.2.9.RELEASE and mysql-connector-java/8.0.21 and MySQL Server "5.7.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)" (MAMP on osX, I know it is old...). Did you ever manage to solve your problem?